# Loop to get next unavailable number in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I want to query a table to see if Number exists, if yes check same for Number+ 1 and use recursion. I need to output the next higher value that does not exists.

Example:

Table_A

```
**id - Number - Year**
**11 -  01    - 2021**
**12 -  02    - 2021**
**13 -  10    - 2021**
**18 -  11    - 2021**
**19 -  12    - 2021**
```

query for checkNumber(11) should return - 13

query for checkNumber(13) should return - 13

query for checkNumber(1) should return - 3

How can I create recursive CTE for this or will some other approach be better for doing this in SQL Server?

Comment: Why the `recursion` constraint ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this using following loop:

```
declare @CurrentNumber int;
Set @CurrentNumber = // some initial value can be set based on requirement
WHILE ((Select 1 from Table_A where Number = @CurrentNumber and other conditions..)IS not null)
BEGIN
    SET @CurrentNumber = @CurrentNumber + 1;
END;
PRINT(@CurrentNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a recursive CTE for this.  Instead, you just need to group the ranges of adjacent values and choose the first one.

Assuming that the `number` passed in is within the range of values in the table (as is true of all the examples in the question), you can use:

```
select top (1) max(number) + 1
from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from table_a a
     ) a
where number >= 1
group by (number - seqnum)
order by min(id);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0e763d0e9e5639f151db41903dfaf116) is a db<>fiddle.